# JPanel repaints/resizes in y (height) but not in x (width), why is that?

Tags: java, swing

Hello my JPanel wont repaint/resize in x, but just for y.
I can't figure out why.

This is my JPanel.

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

private BufferedImage image;

public ImagePanel(String path) {
   try {                
      image = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
      this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));
   } catch (IOException ex) {
        // handle exception...
   }
}


@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0,getWidth(), getHeight(), this);          
    }
}
```

This is how i add it to the JFrame:

```
ImagePanel westPanel = new ImagePanel("pic.PNG");

frame.add(westPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
         .
         .
// adding a JTabel in BorderLayout.CENTER and some buttons and stuff in NORTH and SOUTH
         .
         .
frame.pack();
```

Is it because it has to be in CENTER of the frame borderlayout? Or can it be done in the WEST?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));
```

Don't set the preferred size.

Instead override the `getPreferredSize()` method:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize()
{
    return new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
}
```

> Is it because it has to be in CENTER of the frame borderlayout? Or can it be done in the WEST?

If the image is added to the CENTER then the image will be the size of the space available to the frame, so both horizontal and vertical will be resized.

If the image is added to the WEST then the layout respects the width and only the height is resized to fill the height of the frame. So, yes, adding the image to the WEST is probably the cause of your problem.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information about how the constraints affect the layout for each layout manager.

If you need more help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.